# In Java, is there a method to get hold of a server object through a socket connected to its serverSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, client, serversocket

If you have a Java client Socket connected to a Java server's ServerSocket, how do you then obtain the Java server object in the client class?

I have had a look at the Socket class and there seems to be no method for getting hold of a server object through the Socket.connect()ion.

The reason I am asking, is that I would like to send an instruction from my client to the server to deregister the client from subscribing to further updates from the server. My server-client relationship is based on the Observer pattern.

To carry out the instruction, I believe I need to obtain the server object.

I am asking this question because I have not found anything on Google or stackoverflow.com which combines the Observer pattern with server-client socket relationships.

Of course that may indicate my approach is terminally flawed, but if it is, let it be a warning to others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not 100% clear what you're asking, but here goes.

If you want the remote client to indicate to the server side that it is done, then have it send a message that the server side understands to mean done, then simply close the socket object on the server side and on the client. The server socket may continue listening for more connections if appropriate.

If the socket handling the client connection on the server side is to shut down the server socket so it will no longer listen for incoming connections, then simply pass both sockets to the code that is handling the socket which is handling the client connection.

Comment: +1 and thinking of accepting. Thanks Bill in particular for the second paragraph. It's a lot simpler than I thought. I must have been getting confused because I'm trying to implement a GUI with AbstractActions at the same time. I will start afresh and work on the logic before the GUI.